# How to conclude on the equilibrium point for the Jacobian matrix

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I am trying to classify the equilibrium point of this system

x' = $-2xy$

y' = $-3x^2 -y^2 + 4$

When I find the equilibrium points, I get $$(0,0) , (0,-2), (\frac{-2}{\sqrt3},0), (\frac{2}{\sqrt3},0)$$

The Jacobian matrix gives
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -2y  & -2x  \\
    -6x &  -2y \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

So for equilibrium point (0,0), I get
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0  & 0  \\
    0 &  0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Can I conclude that the system is nonhyperbolic at this point? Or there a classification for this?

Comment: The origin is not an equilibrium point.

Comment: I just crossed checked, that's right. But assuming we have such a case with the origin as the equilibrium point. What would the conclusion be?

Comment: Further analysis would be needed. Lyapunov mainly.